# Webhook on specific file in repository?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, bitbucket, webhooks

I would like to setup a webhook on my Github/Bitbucket repo that whenever the "tags" version file is updated. I don't want to deploy and build my application (Jenkins using AWS containers) until the tags file is also updated. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could consider using the [Jenkins Generic Webhook Trigger](https://plugins.jenkins.io/generic-webhook-trigger), and parse the payload of the Github `push` event (see [Event Types & Payloads)](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent)

The plugin will allow you to parse certain data from the payload, and can conditionally trigger a build depending on the result.

Also note, there is an example in the plugin repo for your specific use case of [triggering a build when a specific file changes](https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin/blob/master/src/test/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/gwt/bdd/github/github-push-trigger-when-specific-file-changes-to-branch.feature).

Comment: Thank you so much for a quick response :)